# How to abort shutdown in Windows (XP|Vista) programatically?

Tags: winapi, shutdown, system-shutdown

I want to be able to 1. detect (and, if needed 2. abort) OS shutdown from my application, preferably by using the Windows API.

I know that it is possible to abort shutdown manually using the command `shutdown -a` In the worst case, I could ShellExecute this, but I was wondering if there was a better way to prevent the shutdown programatically.

Maybe it would be enough to be notified programatically that the OS is about to shut down - how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890(VS.85).aspx):

> The `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message is sent when the user chooses to end the session or when an application calls one of the system shutdown functions. If any application returns zero, the session is not ended. The system stops sending `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` messages as soon as one application returns zero.

So, my application's WindowProc now processes the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message and returns `0`.

Didn't expect it to be this simple; as a bonus, it also works on Windows 2000.

Comment: Well, it is correct *enough* for me. There may be some quirks or advanced operations for this message, and CW allows more people to edit.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to 'simply' returning 0 to block a shutdown, it isn't as simple as that if you want to do it in the proper way. Especially on Vista. For example please also read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677(VS.85).aspx

Comment: The article seems to say "it's much more complicated on Vista: Applications that must block shutdown should use the new shutdown reason API." Never in the entire article does it mention a "more proper" way to handle this on XP. Did I miss something?