# How to abort shutdown in Windows Vista and 7 programatically?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, shutdown

In the second example (in the section examples) on this [link](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnMessage.htm), there is a description on using WM_QUERYENDSESSION to abort a shutdown. It also states that this does not work on versions of windows later than XP. This is conflicting with the advice given on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589986/how-to-abort-shutdown-in-windows-xpvista-programatically) here at stackoverflow. What is the correct answer? I do not have a computer with either so I am unable to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some applications got the WM_QUERYENDSESSION handling wrong (Not passing to DefWindowProc, they incorrectly returned 0 even though they did not intend to block shutdown) and so MS changed it with Vista, you now need to call [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376877%28VS.85%29.aspx)

@Konamiman: shutdown.exe -a will abort a "scheduled" shutdown yes, but not a "normal" shutdown by someone calling ExitWindowsEx()

Answer (score 2):

If anything else fails, remember that from command line it is `shutdown.exe -a`; maybe you could invoke this using the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

**EDIT**. When mentioning the Process class I happily assumed that the question was about .NET programming, now I see that .NET is not mentioned neither in the question nor in the tags. Anyway I believe that there are ways to run executables from other programming environments as well.

Comment: You are right that this is a possibility. It just seems like a hack, so I was hoping for other possibilities.